# Make function's behavior depens on type parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript, scala, generics, functional-programming

It's like typeclass in functional style.

Scala example:

```scala
def f[T](implicit t: SomeTrait[T]): SomeTrait[T] = t
```

There is only a type parameter `T`, and the returned data `t` depends on it.

Can I do something similar in Typescript ?

Comment: Note that this question is actually about the data returned by the function, not the return type, so check the edit history.

Comment: I made the edit as I thought the question what about return type but Indeed maybe update it @Lin Lee if the question is more about the `implicit`/TypeClass thing